# Implicitly defined curve

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, homework

Consider the curve $C$ defined by the equation $y\, \sin(x)+x\, \sin(y)+x+y=0$.

1. Find all points of the form $(8,y)$ that lie on $C$.
2. For each point found in part 1, evaluate the derivative $dy/dx$ at that point.
3. Plot the curve and the tangent lines at each of the points found in part 1.

My code is:

```
c = Plot[y*Sin[8] + 8*Sin[y] + 8 + y == 0, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}];
cc = ContourPlot[y*Sin[x] + x*Sin[y] + x + y == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}];
Show[c, cc]
```

I am not sure if I am doing what question asked. My professor mentioned of doing something like this

```
implicit = D[y[x]*x*Sin[x] + x*Sin[y[x]] + x + y[x] == 0, x]
```

Comment: I don't understand how implicit differentiation relates to solving your equation. You can solve your equation with `NSolve[y*Sin[8] + 8*Sin[y] + 8 + y == 0 && -10 < y < 10, y]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the differential system of equations; include forms for the particular values `x == 8` and an arbitrary nonzero choice for `dx`, say `dx = 1`:

```
F = y*Sin[x] + x*Sin[y] + x + y;
dF = Dt[F] /. {Dt[x] -> dx, Dt[y] -> dy};

sols = Solve[{x - 8, dx - 1, F, dF} == 0 && -20 < y < 20]   (* or NSolve *)
```

Use solutions to get whatever info you want, such as the points and the tangent line equations:

```
pts = {x, y} /. sols;
tl = Y - y == dy/dx (X - x) /. sols  /. {X -> x, Y -> y};  (* variable hocus-pocus *)
```

Plot them:

```
ContourPlot[{ff == 0, tl} // Flatten // Evaluate,
 {x, -5, 15}, {y, -15, 5},
 Epilog -> {Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternative setup of the differential:

```
jac = D[F, {{x, y}}];
dF = jac.{dx, dy};
```

Answer (score 6):

First find the y values like Carl Woll proposed.

```
nsol = NSolve[y*Sin[8] + 8*Sin[y] + 8 + y == 0 && -20 < y < 20, y]

(*    {{y -> -5.8196}, {y -> -2.84462}, {y -> -0.891837}}    *)
```

Define the points

```
pts = Thread[List[8, y /. nsol]]

(*    {{8, -5.8196}, {8, -2.84462}, {8, -0.891837}}    *)
```

Solve for the gradient

```
solys = Solve[D[y[x]*Sin[x] + x*Sin[y[x]] + x + y[x] == 0, x], y'[x]]

(*   {{Derivative[1][y][x] -> (-1 - Sin[y[x]] - Cos[x] y[x])/(
       1 + x Cos[y[x]] + Sin[x])}}   *)

yt[x_] = y'[x] /. First@solys
```

Calculate the gradient at the found points

```
grad = (yt[8] /. y[8] -> #[[2]]) & /@ pts

(*   {-0.250838, 0.198087, -0.0501247}   *)
```

Plot it in the ContourPlot

```
ContourPlot[{y*Sin[x] + x*Sin[y] + x + y == 0, 
  Thread[y == Plus[y /. nsol, grad (x - 8)]]} // Flatten // 
  Evaluate, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  Epilog -> Point@pts]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_, y_] := x Sin[y] + x
g[x_, y_] := f[x, y] + f[y, x]
p = {8, y} /. Solve[g[8, y] == 0 && -2 Pi < y < 2 Pi, y];
cp = ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[p]}];
dydx = Dt[y, x] /. First@Solve[Dt[g[x, y], x] == 0, Dt[y, x]];
tg[pt_, u_] := 
  dydx (u - pt[[1]]) + pt[[2]] /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]};
Show[cp, Plot[tg[#, s] & /@ p, {s, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_, y_] := y*Sin[x] + x*Sin[y] + x + y
yprimes =  y - # - (x - 8) #2 ==  0 & @@@ ({y, -Divide @@ Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]} /.
  Solve[f[8, y] == 0 && -20 < y < 20, y] /. x -> 8);

ContourPlot[Evaluate@Flatten@{f[x, y] == 0, yprimes}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  MeshFunctions -> {# &}, Mesh -> {{8}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]],
  PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]